# Database sync from live server to local mahine

Tags: php, mysql, database, synchronization

I made a web application using php and mysql.That application is working in both live server and local server.I synced data from local server to live server.After that i want to sync the data from live server to local server.Is there any method to sync data from live server to local server?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you automate the process to `sync data from local server to live server`? If not why not just repeat the process in reverse?

Comment: I already done the databse sync from local machine to server.

Comment: If you have ssh access to the server its possible to automate both ways using something like https://deployer.org

Comment: My plan is to place a button in live server application .Sync the live database to local server when the button press

Comment: I there any method to identify local machine from live server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, but you can connect from your local application to your live MySQL DB so you will have synced data